# Getting "TypeError: Unhashable type: 'Point'" while trying to use GeoPandas

Tags: typeerror, geopandas

I am currently trying to plot a series of location points on top of an existing map (.shp file). But I run into a "TypeError: Unhashable type: 'Point'" error while trying to plot them. Here is this code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
street_map.plot(ax = ax, alpha = 0.4, color = "grey")
geo_df[geo_df['geometry']].plot(ax = ax, markersize = 20, color = "blue", marker = "o", label="location")
plt.legend(prop={'size': 15})
```

And this is the error message that shows up. Is this because I am indexing it incorrectly? I'm just trying to overlay a a df with a list of coordinates over an existing shp file of the street layout of San Mateo County:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most 
recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-e41b19a6a359> in <module>
  1 fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
  2 street_map.plot(ax = ax, alpha = 0.4, color = "grey")
----> 3 geometries = geo_df[geo_df['geometry']].apply(lambda x: 
x.wkt).values
  4 plt.legend(prop={'size': 15})

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in __getitem__(self, key)
1325         GeoDataFrame.
1326         """
->1327         result = super().__getitem__(key)
1328         geo_col = self._geometry_column_name
1329         if isinstance(result, Series) and 
isinstance(result.dtype, GeometryDtype):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in 
__getitem__(self, key)
2804             if is_iterator(key):
2805                 key = list(key)
->  2806             indexer = 
self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True) 
[1]
2807 
2808         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py 
in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
1545             if len(ax) or not len(key):
1546                 key = self._convert_for_reindex(key, axis)
-> 1547             indexer = ax.get_indexer_for(key)
1548             keyarr = ax.reindex(keyarr)[0]
1549         else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
 packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_indexer_for(self, 
target, **kwargs)
4499         """
4500         if self.is_unique:
-> 4501             return self.get_indexer(target, **kwargs)
4502         indexer, _ = self.get_indexer_non_unique(target, 
**kwargs)
4503         return indexer

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_indexer(self, 
target, method, limit, tolerance)
2751                 )
2752 
-> 2753             indexer = 
self._engine.get_indexer(target._ndarray_values)
2754 
2755         return ensure_platform_int(indexer)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in 
pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_indexer()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.lookup()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Point'
```

Comment: Please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking a question, and ideally post a full [mre] so we can help diagnose the issue. I'm guessing though that this is the culprit: `geo_df[geo_df['geometry']]`. What are you trying to do here? You can't index the dataframe with a geometry column - did you mean `geo_df[geo_df['geometry'].notnull()]` or something?

Comment: Sorry, just included it

Comment: Did you look at the rest of my comment? what are you trying to achieve with this step? does it work if you drop the indexing part and just replace `geo_df[geo_df['geometry']].plot(...` with simply `geo_df.plot(...`?

Comment: so i have one data frame that has the time stamp in one column and geogaphy(longitude, latitude) in the other column. I am trying to overlay that on an existing .shp file of the street layout of the county of san mateo.

Comment: just plot `geo_df` - there's no need to filter it.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `geo_df[geo_df['geometry']]`, you are using `geo_df['geometry']` as a mask. That is where the error comes from. Since you haven't posted a reproducible example, my guess is that your wanted to use a single column (while there's no reason to do so in practice). Try following:

```py
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
street_map.plot(ax = ax, alpha = 0.4, color = "grey")
geo_df['geometry'].plot(ax = ax, markersize = 20, color = "blue", marker = "o", label="location")
```

Comment: I tried running this piece of code and it gives me an output, however the scale of both of the graphs is completely off. Is there a reason for this? Thanks for the help, really appreciate it

Comment: @Dubs we can't guess what's going on with your plots/data without knowing more about what you're doing and what's not working. please see [ask] and create a [mre] if you want help. if you have a new question about aligning axes, look for existing answers on that topic, and if it's a novel question, feel free to ask it!

Comment: @Dubs `street_map` is probably in a different projection than `geo_df`.